# How to build CCLS on Linux (performed on Fedora)?

Tags: c++, c, cmake, makefile

I have tried using CMake to build ccls many times and I have just about given so if anyone has a way to do it that would be mega helpful.

I am on Fedora Linux and I am using the repo to get ccls as the prebuilt binaries don't work.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get it to work on Fedora (I don't see any reason why it shouldn't work on other Linux distros) this is how I did it step by step:

Quick note: You  may want to use `sudo yum install clang-devel` and `sudo yum install llvm-devel` since they potentially hold needed dependencies. Also make sure you have downloaded the other things you will need as instructed on the ccls wiki.

1. Firstly I used `git clone --depth=1 --recursive https://github.com/MaskRay/ccls` to clone the repo into a folder.
2. Secondly I went into the ccls folder and used `cmake .`. Which built the required things.
3. Thirdly I the used the `make` command to fully build the repo and generate the ccls executable.
4. Then I created a bin directory in the home directory and moved the ccls executable into it.
5. Then I went into the .bashrc to add ccls to the system path and added the line `export PATH="/home/$USER/bin:$PATH"` to the final line of the bashrc. Then exited the file and used `source ~/.bashrc` to force a reset
6. Finally I added the ccls language server settings to the coc config:

```
{
  "languageserver": {
    "ccls": {
      "command": "ccls",
      "filetypes": ["c", "cpp", "cuda", "objc", "objcpp"],
      "rootPatterns": [".ccls-root", "compile_commands.json"],
      "initializationOptions": {
        "cache": {
          "directory": ".ccls-cache"
        },
        "client": {
          "snippetSupport": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Alternatively you can (if you are using coc) use `CocInstall coc-clangd` in vim or nvim, which is a way you can get something similar to ccls for programming.